# My phone is no longer downloading from playstore

Tags: google-play-store, 6.0-marshmallow

Please I bought solo aspire 4 phone I was doing downloading from play store but I noticed since 18hrs now I  cant download again when my download from play store reaches 23%-45%. It's stop downloading and will won't install too
Please what is the solution for that.

Comment: Try to clear cache and data of native download manager

Answer (score 0):

As you are not seeing any error, it is really hard to provide you a solution. 
but as part of troubleshooting.

just go to Settings > App > Play Store and clear cache and clear Data.

If that does not work, you can download latest Google Play Store (Google it for APK) and copy it on your device and manually install it again.

Even if that does not work, then last resort is to do a factory reset.

Lastly, you recently bought your phone and so you have warranty, let the service center guys take the headache. 
(I am assuming, you are not rooted).